# SharePoint 2010 Virtual Machine DNS Issue

Tags: sharepoint-2010, dns, virtual-machine

I recently created a new SharePoint 2010 image for our virtual machine here at work. After installation and configuration is done, it usually opens a page pointing to your computer name. I have a problem however in all images I create. When SharePoint finishes configuration and goes to the computer's local url (eg. "http://yourcomputername/") I get DNS_UNRESOLVED_HOSTNAME error. However, when I change the url to "http://localhost/" it allows me to go to the home page of my SharePoint site.

Any ideas what might be the problem? I'm using VMWare Player for setting up the image and I have Windows Server 2008 R2 as my base OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out after recreating my virtual machine that it was just a setting issue and nothing more.